# Exception (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) encountered during startup: Unknown CF b4a136b0-1e84-11e7-a3cb-f5a2feb33aff

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cqlsh, bigdata, nosql

While starting Cassandra I ran into the following error:

```
Exception (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) encountered during startup: Unknown CF b4a136b0-1e84-11e7-a3cb-f5a2feb33aff
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown CF b4a136b0-1e84-11e7-a3cb-f5a2feb33aff
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find any fruitful solution other than to drop the data.

Comment: Try restart the node, If not work then Paste the full error stacktrace

Comment: I tried but no progress.

Comment: Is this logged as `Error`or as `Warn`?

Comment: its the error and the execution halts , i.e cassandra didnt starts

Comment: @Piyush_Rana May i ask you how were you able to fix this problem. I am facing it right now. Thanks.

Comment: No @pradeepchhetri  Only fix I found is to drop the data and restart Cassandra. So to overcome this issue or not to replicate it you need to make sure that you do not run some parallel table creations queries

Comment: Thank you Piyush for the quick response, I was finally able to fix it after some good hours of effort. We need to delete some cas views to finally stop this error